Looking for a fully managed webhook scheduling service to use with NodeJS
I have a service that I've developed for personal use. It has just one user (me) and so I am trying to make it as cheap as possible to run. It'll serve not more than 10-15 requests in a day. I am looking for a fully managed service (paid is fine) that will allow me to schedule tasks/alarm webhooks in the future at a certain time, that way my service can be scaled down to 0 to save on cloud costs.
Ideally I'm looking to be able to do
const res = await axios.request({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'api.scheduler-service.com/createAlarm',
  body : {
    method: 'GET'
    url: 'myservice.com/task/123',
    scheduledAt: 'some timestamp'
  }
})

Whenever I have some functionality that needs to completed later (at a dynamically determined timestamp) I can save the alarm in this external service and my service can go back to sleep. This way, my service can just say "Hey, I'm going to need you to ping me at {timestamp} so that I dont forget to do this". The reminders that I'll be setting can be thought of as completely random and unpredictable so any form of Crons will not work for me. They will be alarms that need to be executed just one time, if I need more alarms I want to simply ping the API again.
I've tried using Google Cloud Tasks but it's been a real hassle getting it setup and I want something simple to use. After all the service will handle very low amounts of traffic. Jobs/Crons are not helpful because my server needs to stay awake to keep track of these, thus looking for an external solution.
Tried Google Cloud Tasks, PipeDream and CloudFlare Durable Object Alarms but again, too complex for the use case.

I know you mentioned you tried Pipedream, but I'm curious what didn't work for you (full disclosure, I'm a product manager there).
Here's a really basic example I just configured: https://pipedream.com/new?h=tch_GKfJxq
That workflow template receives a webhook with this example body:
{
  "url": "https://myservice.com/task/123", <- endpoint you want to call later
  "scheduledAt": "1720451433805" <- timestamp when you want to call it
}

Then it figures out how far in advance that timestamp is, and pauses further execution of the workflow until then (that uses the $.flow.delay() method, which supports between 1 millisecond and up to 1 year).
After the delay, execution resumes and makes a simple GET request to the URL you passed in to the webhook trigger.
Of course it can be expanded to handle other use cases, errors, etc, but hopefully this points you in the right direction!
